# « Au soleil » vs « dans le soleil » vs « sous le soleil »

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

Ceci provient de la page 81 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* de Mary Crocker :

> Prepositions in Adverbial Clauses of Manner
>   In many adverbial phrases where *in, by* or *on* are used in English, **à** is used in French.
>
> Mettez les vêtements **au soleil** pour les faire sécher. = *Put the clothes in the sun to make them dry.*

De [*La femme et le patin*](http://books.google.com/books?id=dsXoC9DUAp4C&pg=PT17&dq=%22dans+le+soleil%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=AhzvUvvwMK6eiAfO0oGYAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) par Pierre Louÿs :

> Je l'imaginais partout, debout contre un arbre, assise sur un banc. couchée sur la pelouse, accoudée derrière les balustres ou levant les bras **dans le soleil** jusqu’à une branche chargée de fruits.

De la [page 291](http://books.google.com/books?id=4rUPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA291&dq=%22dans+le+soleil%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=ihrvUuvXK8fOiAfUrYDQBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) de *Origine de tous les cultes*, volume 3 par Charles-François Dupuis :

> Or, cette fonction est celle qu'exerce le soleil dans la nature sous la forme, soit du taureau ou d'Osiris, soit sous celle du bouc place sous le taureau, ou du Dieu Pan. Cette qualité active que personne ne peut méconnaitre **dans le soleil**, et qui, après l'hiver et aux approches du printemps, se manifeste tous les ans au renouveau...

1. Prière de faire ressortir les points communs et les divergences ? Sont-elles parfaitement interchangeables ici ? Pourquoi ou pourquoi pas ? J'ai hasardé [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sous+le+soleil%2Cdans+le+soleil%2Cau+soleil&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csous%20le%20soleil%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdans%20le%20soleil%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cau%20soleil%3B%2Cc0).
2. Que peut-on extrapoler/généraliser au sujet de « à + ...  » vs « dans + ... » vs « sous + ... » ?

Comment: Mince, je n'ai répondu que sur les deux premiers !... Mais attention tout de même que, sur stackexchange, les questions sont [en rapport avec](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) **You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face**. Donc, est-ce vraiment un problème devant lequel vous êtes dans le cadre d'une pratique du français ?

Comment: On ne peut rien généraliser sur l'emploi des prépositions seules car très souvent leur emploi dépend aussi du verbe qu'elles suivent.

Comment: @Istao: de toute façon il n'y a pas de rapport entre les exemples donnés par le PO dans 1 et 2 où il est question de la chaleur/du rayonnement du soleil (s'il n'est pas visible/sensible au moment décrit on ne pourra pas employer le mot), et dans 3 où c'est l'astre qui est désigné indépendamment de son rayonnement (la phrase peut être dite sans tenir compte du « temps qu'il fait »). La question mélange tout.

Comment: Que signifie « J'ai hasardé » selon vous?

Comment: @Maxime: Ceci signifie « j'ai essayé », mais dans un sens plus risqué ?

Comment: @LePressentiment ce terme n'est pas utilisé dans le langage courant (en tout cas en France). Vous devriez vous limiter aux verbes essayer ou tenter. J'aurais peut-être dit : « J'ai essayé de les comparer sur Google Ngram. ».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le terme courant pour désigner un placement extérieur ensoleillé est ***au soleil*** ([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soleil) II.A.2.a.α). Le sens premier de « au soleil » est « directement exposé au soleil », c'est-à-dire à l'extérieur, de jour, par temps peu nuageux, et pas à l'ombre. Mais on peut aussi utiliser « au soleil » si toutes les conditions ne sont pas réunies, par exemple par opposition à « à l'ombre » (même si le temps est couvert) ou à « sous les nuages » ou « sous la pluie » (référence seulement au temps qu'il fait et pas au fait de ne pas être à l'ombre).

> On grelotte sitôt que le soleil vous quitte, et, au soleil, on a trop chaud. (Gide)
>   Je vais passer mes vacances au soleil dans un pays tropical.

L'expression *sous le soleil* ([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soleil) II.A.2.a.δ) n'a en général pas de sens qui se réfère au temps qu'il fait ou à l'absence d'ombre. *Sous le soleil* désigne les affaires terrestres, le monde des hommes, la vie de tous les jours, par opposition au ciel qui est le domaine du divin, de l'immanent.

Il est rare d'utiliser *dans le soleil* autrement que pour parler de ce qui se passe dans l'objet qu'est le soleil. Dans la phrase de Pierre Louÿs, « levant les bras dans le soleil » se place du point de vue (au sens propre) du narrateur : les bras de la personne sont dans la région du champ de vision du narrateur qui est occupée par le soleil. On pourrait dire « vers le soleil » ou « dans la direction du soleil » en perdant le côté poétique mais sans changer le sens.

Quant à la citation de Dupuis, elle est complètement sur un autre plan, parce que *dans* n'a pas un sens spatial : « personne ne peut méconnaître cette qualité dans le soleil » signifie « personne ne peut ignorer que le soleil a cette qualité ».

On ne peut pas vraiment généraliser sur l'emploi des prépositions. Le choix de telle ou telle préposition se fait au cas par cas.

Comment: @LePressentiment Cela signifie « le soleil, considéré comme un objet ». C'est une manière de préciser qu'on parle de l'objet physique, ce n'est pas une métaphore ou une métonymie.

Comment: Merci. Ainsi, `que` fonctionne à titre d'un pronom relatif ? Si oui, devrait-on employer `qui` ici ? `l'objet` est le sujet dont l'objet direct est `le soleil` ? Je vous prie de répondre dans votre réponse.

Comment: @LePressentiment Oui, *que* est ici un pronom relatif. Il est attribut du sujet dans la subordonnée, donc on utilise *que* : *qui* est utilisé seulement quand le pronom est sujet.

Comment: Merci. Encore que je ne comprenne pas encore, j'ai démarré un nouveau affiche (= post)? pour ne pas faire traîner les questions dans les commentaires :http://french.stackexchange.com/q/9100/1995.

Answer (score 2):

- **Au soleil** est [présenté dans le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soleil) :

  > (Exposé) à la lumière du soleil; (situé) dans un endroit, un pays ensoleillé.
- Pour **Dans le soleil** je n'ai pas trouvé de référence, mais
  intuitivement ça m'évoque deux sens : soit, comme si le soleil était
  une boîte, dedans lui (*Il y a du gaz dans le soleil*), soit, sur
  terre, quelque chose ou quelqu'un qui est en situation
  d'éblouîssement (*Il y a un panneau sur la route, mais comme il est
  dans le soleil je ne peux pas le lire*)

Ces deux expressions ne sont pas interchangeables, mais de nombreux exemples littéraires montrent que les artistes s'ingénient à le faire quand même :

- [Dans le soleil ou le brouillard](http://www.bide-et-musique.com/song/7983.html) : *Dans le soleil ou le brouillard
  Il faut tracer jour après jour Un chemin pour la bonne nouvelle*
- [Dans le soleil et dans le vent](http://www.musikiwi.com/paroles/nana-mouskouri-soleil,vent,20743.html) de Nana Mouskouri : *Dans le soleil et dans le vent
  Tournant les ailes du vieux moulin
  Elles tourneront aussi longtemps
  Que nous vivrons main dans la main*